# How do I stop apps from graying out and not launching?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Whenever I try to open an app it gets grayed out and won't launch. Also the windows store is called "ms-resource:StoreTitle.

How do I fix my apps so that they correctly launched when clicked?

[image: Start Menu]

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the apps are stuck in update mode and when you click on these apps, a window pops up for few milliseconds and then closes automatically.

Method 1: Reset Windows Store Cache:
Please run wsreset.exe on your PC and see if your issue can be fixed.

Method 2: Download and Run Microsoft Start Menu Troubleshooter

http://aka.ms/diag_apps10

Method 3: Run powershell commands as admin to repair and register the App components:

*Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}*

---

**If comments solution doesn't work, please open CMD as admin and type following commands:**

First this: 
*((Get-ChildItem “HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications”) | Get-ItemProperty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode*

If not work, then these commands:

*Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth*

*SFC /scannow*

---

**Update 2/1:**

Let's try steps below to repair your corrupted main user profile.

Refer to this guide: https://windowsreport.com/corrupt-user-profile-windows-10/

---

Update 2/8

Please also check if there is items under this registry key for your not working apps, if so, delete them to check the results: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\StateChange\PackageList\

Comment: Method 1 pops up with an error saying "ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches Package could not be registered."

Method 2 an error happens the same as method number 1. Under problems found it says Windows Store cache may be damaged.

Method 3 has an error saying "Cannot find path 'C:\AppXManifest.xml' because it does not exist."

Comment: Run powershell commands first: Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted.  Then, try this commands: Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}. I add -allusers switch in this command.

Comment: I tried this on a new user. The windows store and bunch of other apps now work. Unfortunately it's still broken on my main user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try repair the user profile, refer to my update.

Comment: The name of the apps seems to be fixed now but they still won't launch properly.

Comment: Please wait for a while, since apps need time to download and configure in background. if the issue still persists, I need to check your apps event log locate here: %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI%4Operational.evtx

Comment: Update 2/8 worked for me. But I still need to understand why is this happening. What's the root cause.